# Iterate specific dictionary values in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

When i receive a associative array namely dictionaries in django template which as follows

```
 "receivable_aging":    {
      "age5": 235114.91999999998,
      "age4": 235114.91999999998,
      "age3": 0,
      "age2": 0,
      "age1": 0 }
```

I tried to print like this

```
{% for key, value in receivable_aging.items %}
{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to print `age1` to `age4` in ascending order. How can I achieve this without `if` or minimal steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort items in your `views.py`:

```
return render_to_response('page.html', 
    {'receivable_aging': sorted(receivable_aging.items())})
```

Then print them in template:

```
{% for key, value in receivable_aging %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: i want to print age1 to age4 ?